# How to programmatically determine if anonymous access is enabled for a SharePoint 2010 Web Application using C#?

Tags: 2010, development, authentication, web-application, anonymous-authentication

In Central Administration\Manage Web Applications, there is the ability to enable anonymous access on a web application through the authentication providers. Is there a way to programmatically determine if this option is enabled? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have specified in my post, but I was looking for how to do this in C#.  I got the answer I was looking for in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058110/how-to-programmatically-determine-if-anonymous-access-is-enabled-for-a-sharepoin/13064047#13064047) link.  Here's the code I basically wound up using by utilizing the IisSettings property of the SPWebApplication object:

```
Dictionary<SPUrlZone, SPIisSettings> settings = webApplication.IisSettings;

foreach (KeyValuePair<SPUrlZone, SPIisSettings> setting in settings)
{
    bool allowAnon = setting.Value.AllowAnonymous;

    //TODO handle stuff with this info
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$authprov = Get-SPAuthenticationProvider -WebApplication [web application URL] -Zone [zone]
# Check the AllowAnonymous property:
$authprov.AllowAnonymous
```

Should return true or false

http://myspworld.wordpress.com/2012/05/31/anonymous-claims-authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Though I should have specified in my original post that I was looking for how to do this in c#, but I appreciate your answer.